# Angularjs trigger country state dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Can someone please help me make my example of Country/State drop down dependency work?

I intentionally created JSON in this way because I want the dependency to be generic, so I would be able to apply it on any drop down while using only Meta Data and not HTML.

Here's [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/kobiso/TsxTU/11/)  to see an example of the code in JSFidlle

**HTML**

```
Country:<select data-ng-model="Countries" data-ng-options="country.id as country.name for country in Countries.items">
            <option value="">Please select a country</option>
        </select>

State: <select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in currentStates.items">
            <option value="">Please select a state</option>
        </select>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function Controller($scope) {

var Countries = {
    "id": "field10",
    "items": [{
                "id": "10",
                "StateGroupID":"0",
                "name": "United State"
              }, 
              {
                 "id": "2",
                 "StateGroupID":"1",
                 "name": "Canada"
              }]
};

var States =
    {   "id": "field20",
        "StateGroups": [{
            "items": [{  "id": "1",
                       "name": "Alabama"
                      }, 
                      {
                          "id": "2",
                          "name": "Alaska"
                      }, 
                      {  "id": "3",
                       "name": "Arizona"
                      }, 
                      {  "id": "4",
                       "name": "California"
                      }]},

                 [{  "id": "201",
                    "name": "Alberta"
                   }, 
                  {
                      "id": "202",
                      "name": "British Columbia"
                  }, 
                  {
                      "id": "303",
                      "name": "Manitoba"
                  }, 
                  {
                      "id": "304",
                      "name": "Ontario"
                  }]]
};

$scope.Countries = Countries;
$scope.currentStates = States.StateGroups[0];
$scope.$watch('currentStates', function(value, oldValue){
    //alert(value);
    //alert(JSON.stringify(value));
    //$scope.currentStates = (value == "10") ?  States.StateGroups[0] : States.StateGroups[1];
});
```

}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

first, I think there is a little mistake in your JSON, you should have one "items" before the Canadian states

```
          {"items": [{  "id": "201",
                    "name": "Alberta"
                   }, .....
```

After doing this, I would modify your HTML in order to have 2 different model names (the way you did, at the first click you overwrite the list of countries). Then I'll use a different syntax for the ng-repeat, in order to force the value to the StateGroupId

```
 <select data-ng-model="selectedCountry">
            <option ng-repeat='country in Countries.items' value='{{country.StateGroupID}}'>{{country.name}}</option>          
        </select>
```

Doing this allows you to create a function to get the states of the selected group ID :

```
 $scope.getStates=function(){
    console.log($scope.selectedCountry)
     return $scope.backupStates.StateGroups[$scope.selectedCountry].items;
}
```

Then you can use this function to display them using ng-repeat

```
            <select data-ng-model="selectedState" >
              <option value="">Please select a state</option>
              <option ng-repeat='state in getStates()'>{{state.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

I modified your fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/TsxTU/14/ , I hope this is the kind of behavior you wanted :)

Comment: Your answer was very useful to me.
You have directed me to the error in the JSON structure as well as the HTML which helped me better understand my errors and how to fix them and eventually make my example work.
Your Example is better than mine but **why did you use [ng-repeat] instead of [ng-options]**?

Comment: I'm glad it helped you. The first ng-repeat I used is mostly to force the `value` attribute of each item, I find this easier to modify while testing, but you can make it work with ng-options. The second one, I was lazy and I copy/pasted a large part of the ng-repeat 3 lines above ;). So, in short, you can use ng-options if you want, it will work aswell :)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you a bit of refactoring to your data model - it seems tangled. Let's store counties and states in two arrays:

```
$scope.countries = [{
    "name": "USA",
    "id": 1
  },{
    "name": "Canada",
    "id": 2
}];
$scope.states = [{
    "name": "Alabama",
    "id": 1,
    "countryId": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Alaska",
    "id": 2,
    "countryId": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Arizona",
    "id": 3,
    "countryId": 1
  }, {
    "name": "Alberta",
    "id": 4,
    "countryId": 2
  }, {
    "name": "British columbia",
    "id": 5,
    "countryId": 2
}];
```

Having this, we can write [`select`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect)s for data:

```
<select data-ng-model="country" data-ng-options="country.name for country in countries" data-ng-change="updateCountry()">
  <option value="">Select country</option>
</select>
<select data-ng-model="state" data-ng-options="state.name for state in availableStates">
  <option value="">Select state</option>
</select>
```

It's a pity we cannot use `if` expressions in selectors - if we can, we do not need a single line of JS! But we need:

```
$scope.updateCountry = function(){
  $scope.availableStates = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.states, function(value){
    if(value.countryId == $scope.country.id){
      $scope.availableStates.push(value);
    }
  });
}
```

And that's all. [Here is a working plunk for you.](http://plnkr.co/edit/mQvoxoSdFNTvkQxqt53n?p=preview)

Comment: If a countryCode is added to the states, it is much simpler to use a filter: ng-options="state.name for state in states | filter:{country:countryCode}"

Comment: Probably should use value.countryId === $scope.country.id as its strict equal'ness.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to fix is to refer the `currentCountry` in the 2nd select and no need to use the `$watch` to achieve your requirement.

```
<select data-ng-model="currentCountry" data-ng-options="country.name for country in Countries.items">

<select data-ng-model="currentItem" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in States.StateGroups[currentCountry.StateGroupID].items">
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5dkuj/)**</kbd>

Comment: Your answer is good however you changed the HTML, while I specifically mentioned that I would like to keep current HTML as is and use JavaScript.

Comment: @scription I can't see that in your question. You mentioned something about the data structure but that is totally different from HTML.

Answer (score 0):

**angular-country-picker**
   bower install angular-country-picker (or)
   npm install angular-country-picker

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-country-picker/country-picker.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-country-picker/country-picker.js"></script>

       angular.module('webApp', ['puigcerber.countryPicker']);

       <select ng-model="selectedCountry" pvp-country-picker="name"></select>

       angular.module('myApp', ['puigcerber.countryPicker'])
       .config(function(pvpCountriesProvider) {
        pvpCountriesProvider.setCountries([
        { name: 'Abkhazia', alpha2: 'AB'},
        { name: 'Kosovo', alpha2: 'XK'},
        { name: 'Nagorno-Karabakh', alpha2: 'NK'},
        { name: 'Northern Cyprus', alpha2: 'KK'},
        { name: 'Somaliland', alpha2: 'JS'},
        { name: 'South Ossetia', alpha2: 'XI'},
        { name: 'Transnistria', alpha2: 'PF'}
      ]);
    });
```