# ng-change not working angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i am creating a web app in which i have two dropdownlist, i want to change data of dropdownlist 2 on dropdownlist 1 change

```
<tr>
    <td>
        state
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-change="gcity()" ng-init="state = 'state'" ng-model="state">
            <option ng-repeat="o in statefunc" value="state">{{o.state}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        City
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-init="city = 'select'" ng-model="city">
            <option ng-repeat="o in city" value="city">{{o.city}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

this is my dropdown if i select a particular state the city should be populated as per my state

but it is not working and even in console not showing any data,

then i tried ng-click

```
<tr>
    <td>
        state
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-click="gcity()" ng-init="state='state'" ng-model="state">
            <option ng-repeat="o in statefunc" value="state">{{o.state}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        City
    </td>
    <td>
        <select ng-init="city='select'" ng-model="city">
            <option ng-repeat="o in city" value="city">{{o.city}}</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

ng-click works fine but i want to use ng-change which is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I suggest use a different json array as below.  Only difference is state is an array of state objects and not a state to cities key, value pair.
>   when a state is selected the ng-model is state object with name and cities.  You can only submit the state name and not the cities list, which can be done during submission.
>   with this both selects use the array option for ngOptions select.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'World';
    $scope.data = {
        "states": [{
            "name": "Maharashtra",
            "cities": ["Pune", "Mumbai", "Nagpur"]
        }, {
            "name": "Gujarat",
            "cities": ["Surat", "Ahmedabad", "Baroda"]
        }, {
            "name": "Rajasthan",
            "cities": ["Jaipur", "Ajmer", "Jodhpur"]
        }]
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                state
            </td>
            <td>
                <select ng-model="state" ng-options="state.name for state in data.states">
          <option value=''>Select</option>
          </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                City
            </td>
            <td>
                <select ng-disabled="!state" ng-model="city" ng-options="city for city in state.cities">
            <option value=''>Select</option>
        </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Plunkr:  http://plnkr.co/edit/mtMdbUveeJKMRqmpvHyI?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the same value in all options

```
value="state"
```

Try

```
<option ng-repeat="o in statefunc" value="{{o.state}}">{{o.state}}</option>
```

Example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/aVp4d1JcYWUCdvLYiNb3?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-option` instead of `option` in select tag.Look at below example.

```
<select ng-init="state='state'" ng-options='o.state for o in statefunc' 
ng-change="gcity()" ng-model="state">
</select>
```

Comment: sir but still i cant get comname

Comment: sorry i am not getting city name

Answer (score 0):

Try this now, i have prepared demo for you.

```js
function CountryController($scope) {
  $scope.countries = {
    'india': {
      'india city 1': [],
      'india city 2': [],
      'india city 3': [],
      'india city 4': [],
    },
    'Us': {
      'Us city 1': [],
      'Us city 2': [],
      'Us city 3': [],
      'Us city 4': []
    },
    'Australia': {
      'Australia city 1': [],
      'Australia city 2': [],
      'Australia city 3': [],
      'Australia city 4': []
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" class="container">
  <div ng-controller="CountryController">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="Country">Estado:</label>
      <select class="form-control input-lg" id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="States">Municípios:</label>
      <select class="form-control input-lg" id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i am not getting city

Comment: @API Controls : You need to reinitialize your city variable on called function updateCity() by passing current selected state id, that's it Man :)

Comment: sorry sir but i am very new in angularjs please do help me and pardon me

Comment: before that can you please refer this? and let me know. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173717/angularjs-trigger-country-state-dependency

Comment: @API Control : I have just edit my answer and prepared demo for you, let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125896/discussion-between-jigar-prajapati-and-api-controls).